# How to control the name of the context in a migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm following [a blog](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) and came to the spot where I'm supposed to create migrations for the identity model of my application. It states explicitly to run the following two commands.

> dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext
> dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext

I like to set my own spin on stuff so naturally, I had to call the migrations and contexts something I made up. While the migrations' names are arbitrary, I discovered that the contexts' names are not. And that surprised me.

Apparently, using a derivate of *PersistedGrantDbContext* (e.g. *PersistedGrants*), produces the error below.

> No DbContext named 'PersistedGrants' was found.

I got curious where that name is hard coded and looked everywhere in the solution. However, no trace of that string are to be found anywhere and I'm baffled where it comes from. In practice, I have no need to change it. But I still want to know how if I would.

I can see that it's mentioned in [the official docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/ef.html#configuration-store-support-for-clients-resources-and-cors-settings) for IDS4. However, it puzzles me that I can't find it reflected in my solution anywhere.

Where can i find that string and what do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a migration, you need to specify the name of the DbContext, such that the current model is compared to its latest snapshot and the differences are reflected in the migration.

> No DbContext named 'PersistedGrants' was found.

That actual string is not in the IDS4 library. [It's logged by EF](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/9ac01d6035c76626d89aa1a3cd8d200db2c3c0e1/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/DbContextOperations.cs#L414-L418) and [defined here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/7d7eb161bf966af534dffa6ae5de51b11dc08499/src/EFCore.Design/Properties/DesignStrings.resx#L287-L289)

IdentityServer separates storage into two: configuration (`ConfigurationDbContext`) and operational data (`PersistentGrantDbContext`).
You can find these in `IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage` assembly.

As for the docs, intro pages are well documented, but there's not much beyond that. The source code is really well commented, and it's a better source of information.

### Further info

- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/DbContexts